# How to add My Image path in MYSQL in automatic selection of fields and inputs?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am getting all data fields in this single line in my controller,because my table fielname and html inputs names are same.

```
     $post= $this->input->post();
```

But now The problem is, I also want to add the image path to save in the DB. For image path I need to define the image path which is not possible in dynamic selection, but after defining path, other fields' insertion fail.

Image code is"

```
     function add_image(){  
         $post= $this->input->post(); 
         if($this->form_validation->run('add_product') && $this->upload->do_upload('img1')){
             $img1= base_url("uploads/".$data['raw_name'].$data['file_ext']);
             $post['img1']=$img1;
             $post= $this->input->post();
             if($this->add->add_product($post)==TRUE){

                 $this->db->close();
                 $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Product has been added successfully');
                 return redirect('admins/pages/add_product_page');

        }  elese {
           echo 'failled';
        }
    }
```

Comment: That code has syntax errors.  What is the specific error you are receiving?

Comment: Remove the $post= $this->input->post(); before add product and it will work sure... You are reassigning the $post var with post method array and that's the reason img path not going in sql query and you are getting error in insert query..

Comment: what is the error you facing?

Comment: if i remove this $post= $this->input->post();... then other field need to be inserted in form of array... so don't want to use array for data insertion just using active record.

Comment: dislaying 'Failled'.  Muhammad Usman

Comment: Ha ha ha... I mean remove    $post= $this->input->post(); after  $post['img1']=$img1; because u already storing all post array data in $post before validation. Reassigning the $post again with post will remove your img path value... And you can use db last query to see what query being made by request..

Comment: Thanks....  Success..........  Bro Neeraj Singh

Comment: You are welcome.. :)

Comment: Then Why the path of first Image  is saving in all three images fields in DB table....
even I store all in different variable
              
            $img1= base_url("uploads/".$data['raw_name'].$data['file_ext']);
            $post['img1']=$img1;
            $img2= base_url("uploads/".$data['raw_name'].$data['file_ext']);
            $post['img2']=$img2;
            $img3= base_url("uploads/".$data['raw_name'].$data['file_ext']);
             $post['img3']=$img3;